# Чтение с определенной строки в файле

Tags: c#

Как организовать чтение файла с определенной строки (номер строки известен) до конца файла?

Comment: @PashaPash, а там ответ правильный?

Comment: @Visman вполне (если файл нужно обрабатывать построчно). и полностью совпадает с одним из ответов в этой теме.

Answer (score 2):

Похожий ответ на вопрос есть в [англоязычном so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262985/4278250):

```
const int skipRowCount = 10;   //сколько строк пропустить, напишите свою циферку
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(FileName).Skip(skipRowCount);
```

Чтобы получить цельную строку, можно прибегнуть к следующему:

```
const int skipRowCount = 10;   //сколько строк пропустить, напишите свою циферку
string file = File.ReadLines(FileName)
                    .Skip(skipRowCount)
                    .Aggregate(
                        new StringBuilder(), 
                        (sb, next) => 
                                sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)
                                    .AppendLine(next);
                            ).ToString();
```

Comment: С Aggregate плохой способ - постоянная конкатенация строк в цикле. Лучше string.Join.

Comment: Можно в Aggregate использовать StringBuilder: `.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, next) => sb.AppendLine(next)).ToString();`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, отличное замечание, обновил в соответствии с ним свой ответ)